# Define multiple TokenStore(s) in Spring secuirty OAUTH

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a Spring Security `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` configuration which is supporting password and refresh_token grant types.

```
clients
        .inMemory()
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
        ...;
```

The `TokenStore` i am using is `JwtTokenStore`, thus the refresh_token and access_token are generated as JWT as i am using the `DefaultTokenServices`

The question is how can i have the refresh_token generated and managed by `JdbcTokenStore` while the access_token still get generated and managed by `JwtTokenStore`?

I have thought about extending `DefaultTokenServices` or implementing `AuthorizationServerTokenServices` but i'm not sure if there is not any other way offered by the default spring-secuirty config.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, to achieve stored tokens (both access token and refresh token) and have JWT encoded tokens at the same time, is provide token store with `tokenEnhancer` of type `JwtAccessTokenConverter`.

```
@Bean
protected TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}

@Bean
protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("client_trusted")//...
    ;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .tokenEnhancer(jwtTokenEnhancer()) // <- tokens are encoded in JWT
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

With this approach you can easily revoke (or remove) `refresh_token`. So authorization server will not provide new access token in next refreshing token request. And information in JWT stays self contained and resource server can work without interaction with authorization server.

```
@Autowired
protected TokenStore tokenStore;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/revoke")
public void revokeToken(@RequestParam String token) {
    ((InMemoryTokenStore)tokenStore).removeRefreshToken(token);
}
```

Here is complete example of authorization and resource server with js client: https://github.com/pufface/spring-oauth-jwt-demo

Comment: Does this mean, after calling (by "logout"     action)((InMemoryTokenStore)tokenStore).removeRefreshToken(token);That this refreshToken can't not be used anymore to get a new accessToken?
----
I will give it a try!

Comment: Does the tokenStore need to be declared as a bean (e.g. in the class https://github.com/pufface/spring-oauth-jwt-demo/blob/master/oauth2-authorizaion-server/src/main/java/sk/fillo/spring/demo/OAuth2AutorizationServerConfig.java)? I'm asking because I think that it does not to be a bean since it is just used in the java configuration to set up another object (`endpoints` in the `configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer)` method) and hence could just be a method without the `@Bean` annotation.